# Implementing backbutton with infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I have new pages loaded via infinite scroll on my site. Each time a new page is loaded I update the url using HTML5 pushstate API:

```
if(history.pushState) {
    history.pushState(null, null, '/page:' + current_page);
}
```

My urls looks like this:

```
http://mysite.com.com/page:1
http://mysite.com.com/page:2
http://mysite.com.com/page:3
```

and so on...

When the user clicks on an item in the listings (for example on page 2) and then clicks the back button he is taken back to:

```
http://mysite.com.com/page:2
```

But instead of being at the top of the page, he is at the portion from which he clicked. Since page:2 is now loaded at the very top, the part where he is loads anew 
page 3 and he is looking at a post from that page instead.

Is there a way to make the user go back to the top of the page each time the back button is clicked?

I tried using anchor tags and javascript scroll on page load but neither is viable since there are several jumps before the user is taken to the top.

The best example of backbutton working with infinite scroll that I have seen is http://imgur.com but I can't figure out how they do it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a library called [infinite-ajax-scroll](https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll) on github that seems to do what you are looking for. You can initialize it using the `history` option, which will update the hash of the url as you scroll the page.  The only issue is that you'll have to change the way you load your data to work with the library.

```
jQuery.ias({
    ....
    history:true,
    ....
});
```

You could also check out [this](http://tumbledry.org/2011/05/12/screw_hashbangs_building) blog post on tumbledry.org, which explains something closer to what you are trying to do, but I don't think its implemented as well.